# SAS : how copy a folder containing subfolders

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want copy a folder containing subfolders in SAS:

Example of the folder that I want copy :

```
folder_to_copy/
├─ sub_folder_1/
├─ sub_folder_2/
│  ├─ file_sub1
│  ├─ file_sub2
│  ├─ file_sub3
├─ file1/
├─ file2/
```

I've try

```
option xwait xsync;
X copy "folder_to_copy"  "new_folder";
```

But this copy only `file1` and `file2`

and

```
data _null_;
call system ('cp  folder_to_copy new_folder');
run;
```

doesn't work too, this does nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cp -R` if you're using Linux.

```
x 'cp -R folder_to_copy new_folder';
```

Use `robocopy /E` if you're using Windows.

```
x 'robocopy folder_to_copy new_folder /E';
```

Comment: `robocopy` also works and is touted for more features than `xcopy`

Comment: Multithreading is also another one of my favorite features of robocopy. Plus, its name is cool.